# DBExpress de Delphi soporta MariaDB en su ultima version?

Tags: mariadb, delphi

cuando compilo mi apliacacion Delphi con componentes DBExpress, en mi equipo de desarrollo funciona perfecto y se ven los datos, pero cuando llevo el programa a otra pc me da error.

el caso es que ya coloque las librerias dbxmys.dll y libmysql.dll en la carpeta sysWOW64 de windows dado que es de 64 bits y mi aplicacion es de 32 bits.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe con distintas versiones de ambas librerias pero no se que otro factor puede ser.

Edito: Fui poniendo un showmessage en distintas partes del ejecutable, luego puse el siguiente codigo en el evento oncreate del DataModule:

```pascal
procedure TDataModule1.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  admin: TIniFile;
  i, x: integer;
  rutadatos, nombredir: String;
  fechanueva, fecha: TDate;
  fechas: string;
begin
  admin := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'CONFIG.ini');

  with DataModule1.CONEXION do
  begin
    Close;
    DriverName := 'MySQL';

    Params.Values['HostName'] := admin.ReadString('admin', 'IP', '');
    Params.Values['DataBase'] := admin.ReadString('admin', 'bd', '');
    Params.Values['Port'] := admin.ReadString('admin', 'Port', '');
    Params.Values['User_Name'] := admin.ReadString('admin', 'User', '');
    Params.Values['Password'] := admin.ReadString('admin', 'Pass', '');
  end;
  try
    CONEXION.Open;

  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
       ShowMessage('Exception class name = '+E.ClassName);
      ShowMessage('Exception message = ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Es decir antes no tenia el try except, el caso es que obtengo el mismo error solo que la aplicacion se inicia pero no carga los datos.
Que puede ser un AccessViolation en el metodo Open del TSQLConnection?

Edito: el DataModule solo se crea en el source del ejecutable y nunca mas lo vuelvo a instanciar:

```pascal
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TFPRODUCTOS, FPRODUCTOS);
  Application.CreateForm(TFClientes, FClientes);
  Application.CreateForm(TDataModule1, DataModule1);
  Application.CreateForm(TFProveedor, FProveedor);
  Application.CreateForm(TFLP, FLP);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.CreateForm(TZR, ZR);
  Application.CreateForm(TFIVA, FIVA);
  Application.CreateForm(TFCV, FCV);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm4, Form4);
  Application.CreateForm(TCatE, CatE);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm5, Form5);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm6, Form6);
  Application.CreateForm(TCatP, CatP);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm7, Form7);
  Application.CreateForm(TPEDIDO, PEDIDO);
  Application.Run;

end.
```

Y el componente de conexion TSQLConnection esta creado antes de compilar osea no por codigo.

Vuelvo a editar: Obtengo:
Exception class name = EAccessViolation

Exception message = Access violation at address 00000000 in module 'DISTRIBUIDORA.exe'. Read of address 00000000

Exactamente el mismo error que daba antes solo que dentro del except.

Comment: Por favor, no publiques imagenes de mensajes de error. La ventana del mensaje de error soporta _ctrl+c_ para que puedas copiarlo y luego pegalo en la pregunta. ¿Qué te hace pensar que el Access Violation está relacionado de alguna manera con DBExpress? El access violation lo que indica es que se está tratando de acceder a una dirección de memoria que no ha sido asignada a tu programa. Cuando esa dirección es `00000000` lo más probable es que un puntero esté a `nil` (que es 0) y estás usándolo como si apuntara a una dirección válida.

Comment: Recuerda que todas las variables a objetos son punteros. Entonces, hacer algo como `Form1 := nil; Form1.Show();` va a provocar un _Access Violation_ y la dirección mostrada será `00000000`.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que en mi maquina compila y se ejecuta perfectamente. Si hago un paso a paso no obtengo errores. Por eso pense era la libreria. Pero bueno voy a publicar algo de codigo a ver que puede ser

Comment: Si tienes acceso al otro equipo, puedes hacer debug remoto también, o en último caso dejar un log o ir sacando el típico `ShowMesage('bandera 1');`, bandera2, bandera3... para ver qué es lo que está fallando.

Comment: Ahi hice como me dijiste. Ya edite la pregunta y el error esta en el Open del TSQLConnection aparentemente.

Comment: ¿Solamente creas una instancia de este módulo de datos en toda la vida del programa? Si es así, muestra la línea donde lo creas. Un saludo.

Comment: Solo se crea en el source del ejecutable. Ya edite la pregunta nuevamente. Saludos

Comment: Cambia el `with DataModule1.Conexion` por `with Conexion`. ¿Se corrige el problema?

Comment: No. No se soluciona. Obtengo el mismo error, dentro del catch. Solo que abre la aplicacion pero no se ven los datos.

Comment: ¿Hay eventos asociados a la conexión?

Comment: No tiene eventos asociados. Gracias por tu ayuda estimado.

Comment: ¿Estás 100% seguro que el AV se genera en la llamada a `Open`?, ¿cómo lo has determinado?

Comment: Y porque tengo el try catch dentro del cual esta el metodo open y da ese error. Voy a tratar de iniciar la aplicacion sin conectar a ver sino da error. El error sino podria estar en cualquier parte de la aplicacion?

Comment: Mi sospecha es que está en cualquier otro lugar. En Delphi no hay `try/catch` sino `try/except`. Pero, de cualquier manera, si ya se ha iniciado la aplicación, al ocurrir una excepción, si no se maneja, `Delphi` va a mostrar el mensaje de error y continuar con la ejecución de la aplicación. Si la excepción está ocurriendo en el `Open`, tendrías que ver dos mensajes, uno con el tipo de excepción y otro con el mensaje, pues así lo tienes programado. ¿Ves los dos mensajes?

Comment: Volvi a editar la pregunta.Si obtengo el mismo mensaje de error que antes en el except al conectar.

Comment: coloca esto, ¿aparece alguno de los mensajes? `if not assigned(Self) then ShowMessage('self es nil'); if not assigned(Conexion) then ShowMessage('conexion es nil');`

Comment: No, no aparece ninguno de los mensajes.

Comment: Se me ocurrio copiar la libreria dbxmys.dll en la carpeta del ejecutable y obtengo:  
Exception message = DBX Error:  Driver could not be properly initialized.  Client library may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system path. Igual, esta en sysWOW64 el mismo archivo